# Can one somehow retrieve the "host instance" from a private class?

Tags: c++

I have the following setup (simplified):

```
class A {
    public:
        void doBar() {  B b; b.bar();  }

    private:
        int foo;

        class B {
            public: void bar() {  /* do somehting with foo */  }
        };
};
```

Now, VS tells me:

> A non static member reference must be relative to a specific object

Well, okay, that sounds reasonable. However, as this class `B` is private to `A` I can be sure that it will never be used outside of an instance of a (specific) instance of `A` (okay, static methods of `A` are an exception).

So bottom line, is there any chance to get the current instance of `A` from a method of `B`, i.e., the instance from which `B b` was instantiated? I'm especially looking for a clean solution because otherwise I'd just pass in a reference.

Comment: no, this is c++, not java. Pass it to B's ctor

Comment: Class B cannot know *which* instance of class A it belongs to. Just pass a reference!

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a class within another class doesn't create "containment", only scope of the class declaration. Your `B` objects are not - generally speaking - contained by `A` objects, unless you make them so by virtue of how you hold references to each other.

So, no; there is no mechanism by which a `B` is able to determine which instance of `A` created it, because there is nothing special about this situation.

And think about it: the `B` object is created on the stack in your example, but it could have been heap-allocated.  The `A` object might have also been created on the heap with 'new', or on the stack, or on a custom heap, or via 'placement-new'. There is no relation at all between the two objects in memory.